# Memory leak with SocksSocketImpl finalize method

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, amazon-ec2

We have been having OutOfMemory in one of our Web Applications. This application is running on Tomcat on Aamzon EC2 behind an Elastic Load Balancer. From heap dump, most the memory was consumed by SocksSocketImpl objects. Yourkit shows 99% of these objects are in Pending Finalization state. However, somehow they are NOT being finalized and GC'ed. The same application with same setup (same tomcat version and JDK version) on other regions and doesn't have issues.

Has anyone seen this kind of behavior before? Any pointers will be helpful. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you examined/monitored your traffic patterns? Maybe your app that has a memory leak is receiving more traffic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Rico. Traffic was not a problem. Number of Socket objects that are on the heap are more than 50% of the full day traffic. We also have break down by hour. Excessive traffic is definitely NOT a cause.

Comment: Strange.  Are you seeing this consistently? Have you tried several times in the region where you are seeing problems?

Comment: Yes. It happened at least 3 times on the same machine.

Comment: I mean a different machine, not just the same machine in the same region

Comment: What is the exact Java version? What is the garbale collector settings? Please try change settings. I have a memory that there was similar problem with very special GC settings.

Comment: Java version is 1.6.0_30 OpenJDK JVM. GC algorithm is concurrent Mark and Sweep.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem running Tomcat 6.0.39, memory issue started when JDK on Ubuntu server was upgraded with security patches to:

```
java version "1.6.0_30"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.1) (6b30-1.13.1-1ubuntu2~0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Profiled with Eclipse Memory Analyzer, traced to finalizer queue of objects for SSL Connections and Hibernate sessions consuming all memory. Problem resolved by upgrading to:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after upgrading to JVM 1.7.0_51. As suspected, it seems to be a JVM level issue either during socket clean up or GC. The problematic version was 1.6.0_30 OpenJDK.

Comment: I have this problem even with 1.7.0_51 on the AWS beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

Its caused by regression to the openjdk package:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/+bug/1295987

It has been fixed, but is waiting for a new openjdk6 package to be deployed.