# Java Socket/SocksSocketImpl memory clog

Tags: java, sockets, memory-leaks

In our test lab setup we have two hosts, both acting as server/client as they are sending heartbeats to each other.

I was running automated performance tests, and after 5 days RAM consumption  increase was steady but consistent, on a first application. Since the tests **did not** target heartbeat application, this was not expected.

After collecting the heap dump of the problematic host and loading it into MemoryAnalyzer and I found lots of "Unreachable" `SocksSocketImpl` objects. **The number is huge, more than 12K of objects.**

Now, the application does create and use sockets but I am pretty confident, after reviewing the code, that there is no some sort of creation loop there. However, when application quits, socket is not properly closed, but again, the heartbeat application did not restart during those 5 days.

I've read about this in SO question: [Memory leak with SocksSocketImpl finalize method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717814/memory-leak-with-sockssocketimpl-finalize-method)

... however, I am running version `1.7.0_76` and guys there write that the bug was fixed in `1.7.0_51`.

`java -version` output:

```
java version "1.7.0_76"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_76-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.76-b04, mixed mode)
```

Does anyone have a clue what this might be? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the code you did?

Comment: I am sorry, due the my NDA I am unable to do that... :(

Comment: the likelihood that sockets are leaking memory with normal usage is about -1%, so try to create a self-contained example based on your code that leaks.

Answer (score 0):

In socket data transferring , you can prepend the size of data to the  transfer data ,(eg:- 10 byte reserved for the length of data) , if you doing like that on the client side the you can get the size of data to receive ,wait (loop)and collect the full data . I thought i may solve your problem

Comment: How does this help reduce (or keep in check) the number of `SocksSocketImpl` objects? Data transfer works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after days of investigating I finally got to the bottom of it.

My application creates a `ServerSocket` which listens for incoming connections. However, external application's logic was wrong so it used to connect to my app very repeatedly/frequently, causing a massive `Socket` object allocation. In time, connection would be closed and `Socket` would be marked for collection.

The second part of puzzle is that `GC` was never triggered. If I had 12K `Socket`, only 10-20 of those would be "`GC` root reachable" while others would be "Unreachable". If I would force `GC`, all of those would be cleaned up. Since there was only 20-30M consumed of max 500M (set by `-Xmx`), I assume that was the reason why `GC` was never triggered.

I know this answer is not particularly useful, but I am putting it here anyway. Could be helpful to someone..